# UseHttpLogging mask passwords and other sensitive data

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, log4net

I am using Net Core 6. It has a feature UseHttpLogging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which includes logging request body and responses.

Does anyone know the best way to mask or not log request body and or response body for certain endpoints and or certain data? I'm especially concerned with passwords in the request and API tokens in the response.

Comment: I am currently considering making my own middleware to log the Request Body and Response Body of the calls to my Web API and include my own logic for determining whether it includes sensitive data. Any other better way to do this?

Comment: Actually I don't find any information about how to specify endpoint when using HttpLogging, So I'm afraid you can only  write your own middleware